# Changing Background Color Of Playback icons in leanback

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

I am using PlaybackOverLayFragment in Android Tv for playback controls.I want to change the background color when particular icons are selected.But not able to find any public methods to do .Below I have attach the image for clarity.See the playicon background image i.e what I want to change to some other color.

Comment: So you're looking to change the background selection color from the lighter purple to some other color entirely?

Comment: Actually its not light purple its white color with some transparency.But yes that thing only I want to change may be something to green.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to share the answer Dake gave in the [G+ Android TV Developers community](https://plus.google.com/u/1/117063980696316582197/posts/XNafRm2vvjQ) just as a reference for anyone else wondering the same thing.

You can override the focusable resource in your app `res/drawable-v21/lb_control_button_primary.xml`

Or, even simpler, you can override the color `@color/lb_control_button_color`